# How to prevent the displacement of other field which is done by show/hide jquery effect?

Tags: jquery, drupal, field

I have created content type with two fields as shown in following image.

Now following are the detailed information, how all system works,

1. The content type has `Field-1` and `Field-2` in order as its numbers.
2. **Field-1:** The body of the `field-1` has the following `HTML` code.

   ```
   <div class="buttoncontainer">
   <ul class="buttonlist">
   <li><button class="button1">button-1</button></li>
   <li><button class="button2">button-2</button></li>
   <li><button class="buttonl">button-link</button></li>
   </ul>
   <div class="p1" style="display:none">Text to be written here</div>
   <div class="p2" style="display:none">Text to be written here</div> </div>
   ```

And Corresponding `Jquery code`,

```
 (function ($) {
 Drupal.behaviors.myfunction = {
     attach: function(context, settings) {

         $(".button1").each(function (index) {
           $(this).click(function() {
             $(this).parents(".buttoncontainer").children(".p1").toggle("slow");
           });
         });

         $(".button2").each(function (index) {
           $(this).click(function() {
             $(this).parents(".buttoncontainer").children(".p2").toggle("slow");
           });
         });
     }}})(jQuery);
```

3. Hence, it is a typical show/hidden content using the `jquery`. When button-1 clicked the content of `class="p1"` slides below, The P1 has `width 100%` and `height 300px` in css so it displaces the next content. Same true to button-2. buttonl is just link.
4. **Field-2** is just a filed provided by otehr module, hence no custom code.
5. **Issue:** Now what happens when we click `button1` or `button-2`, the corresponding content appears and it displaces the next content which is `field-2` as shown in `image-2`, which is quite normal thing. What I want is as shown in **Image-3**, I want `field-1` and `field-2` resides side by side under non-expanding position and when `button-1` or `button-2` gets clicked it slides their own content as usual but and displace the below content but do not displace the field-2.

Hence I want `field-1` and `field-2` in one line and field-2 does not gets affected by `jquery` of `field-1`. *(for keeping them side by side I can use css `display: inline-block`, `float:left`)*

[image]

Comment: this will be guesswork if you're not providing the css and at least the html that wraps all these elements. A working example would be best

Comment: Hhmmm....I will update. Thanks